# Assign TFS Variable with $ in it

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I need to assign TFS variable with `'MSSQL$Staging'`, unfortunately it is only picking up *MSSQL*. I tried using backtick to escape $ still no luck. When i try to print the value i get only *MSSQL*

```
Write-Host "DBInstance = $(DBInstance)"
```

DBInstance is assigned `MSSQL$Staging`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. After lots of trial and error finally assigning the pipeline variable to new powershell variable and the printing that fixed the issue.

```
$test = '$(DBInstance)'
Write-Host "DBInstance = $test"
```

This gave correct answer.

Thank you